# What exactly to unit test in frontend frameworks? Template vs class

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have a general question regarding unit testing of modern frontend frameworks with example in Angular.

I have a bunch of methods which return boolean, which are used both in the class and in the template.

```
amICo3pmCompany({ company3pmid }: Request3pmResponse.AsObject): boolean {
    return company3pmid === this.userService.getUserInfo()?.company?.id;
}

noActiveAgreement(request: Request3pmResponse.AsObject) {
    return (
        !request.id ||
        (!this.amICo3pmCompany(request) &&
            ![Request3pmStatus.INVITED, Request3pmStatus.CONFIRMED].includes(request.status) &&
            this.wallet.mandatory3pmstatus !== Mandatory3pmStatus.AWAITING_FUNDS)
    );
}
```

and template:

```
<atm-third-party-mandate-agreement
    *ngIf="noActiveAgreement(request); else requestExists"
></atm-third-party-mandate-agreement>

<ng-template #requestExists>
    <ng-container *ngIf="amICo3pmCompany(request); else non3pmCompany">
        <atm-third-party-mandate-company-co3pm
        ></atm-third-party-mandate-company-co3pm>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-template #non3pmCompany>
        <atm-third-party-mandate-company-c
        ></atm-third-party-mandate-company-c>
    </ng-template>
</ng-template>
```

What exactly should I unit test? Unit testing by the definition means we should test the atomic parts of the app, hence class methods. But frontend apps' main goal is to show user some stuff, so it's important to check whether components are rendered properly, based on some combination of methods and checks.

So should I test only the template, only the component class or both of them in my unit test?

Comment: Test the _component_, through its _public interface_. If you put a test boundary between the class and the template by trying to test them separately, that makes it harder to safely refactor at what should be a _private_ interface.

Comment: Totally valid to unit test templates ngIf's, ngFor's and the like. Usually we like to keep the logic in TS but sometimes some of it does end up in the template, for example: what if you have a template driven form, kind of means to test the template yeah?

Answer (score 0):

If we follow the advice from Oncle Bob (Robert C. Martin)  in "Clean Craftsmanship" (ISBN-13: 978-0-13-691571-3), given in Chapter 4, section "The One-to-One Correspondence" he writes: *"Newcomers to TDD are often erroneously taught that for every production module or class named χ, there should be a corresponding test module or class named χTest."* He later explains in lengthy detail, that it is perfectly ok to have just one unit test, that tests 2 or even more classes (or files, compile units) that have a strong coupling.

An Angular Component - Typescript file/class and its corresponding HTML-Template have this strong coupling, which is intentional. So I conclude, there is not need at all to try to write separate unit-tests for them, the contrary is true.

An no, even if we have even more classes (and corresponding templates) tested by one single unit test, that is **not** automatically called a "integration test" instead. The Book even shows pictures of up to 7 classes/files/compile-units covered by one unit-test that Oncle Bob explicitly does **not** call a "integration test".

I strongly agree.